# Need to use a variable in os.system with espeak and aplay commands in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, os.system, espeak

I want my raspberry pi to speak this print command

```
print label + " is " + spos + " and the distance is " + str(distance) + "cm"
```

which has three variables in it.
And this is the command i use in shell that i need to use in python

```
$espeak -s110  "label + " is " + spos + " and the distance is " + str(distance) + "cm"" --stdout | aplay -D sysdefault:CARD=2
```

I've tried it with os.system because i'm not familiar with `subprocess` commands.

```
os.system('espeak -s110  "'label' + is + 'spos' +  and the distance is  + 'str(distance)' + cm" --stdout | aplay -D sysdefault:CARD=2')
```

I'm getting an invalid sytax error. I've tried every version of it and couldn't make it work.

Comment: You have a syntax error in how you are trying to assemble the string for `os.system`. Think about where the `'` and `"` should be and how string concatenation works. Alternatively, see the [documentation for subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) and give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
cmd = 'espeak -s110 "{0} is {1} and the distance is {2} cm" --stdout | aplay -D sysdefault:CARD=2'.format(label, spos, str(distance))

os.system(cmd)
```